# How to access transactions history - sol sent from and received to a particular address in a program?

Tags: anchor, transactions, history

I need to access transactions of a particular address while executing my solana program logic. How do I go about fetching them while my function gets triggered?

Also, what is best way to keep updating the information as more transactions take place? Do, I use some external oracle to call my functions after a fixed period everytime?

Comment: @vicyyn has the only way you can do it as their is no 'event' notification capability within your program.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it **manually** by using [Solana Explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/) and pasting the address.

Or you can use [connection.onAccountChange](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#onAccountChange), the callback will be executed every time the account with that address changes (e.g. new transaction)

Comment: onAccountChange seems to be of help.

But how do I fetch the transactions info inside my program? Also, is using onAccountChange is best way to monitor 100's or 1000's of wallet addresses in case the program's usage scales up?

Comment: you can use `onAccountChange` on a program too, programs are accounts, everything is an account in Solana. For the latter, I'm not sure. I advise you to create another post with that question.